python while function in google sheets
how would I replicate a python while function it sheets, for reference or if this has a simpler solution the code if in python would look like this:
​
upgrade = 0
pool = input()
cost = 100​
costchange = 50
going = True
while going: 
    if cost > pool:
        going = False
    else:
        upgrades += 1
        pool -= cost
        cost += costchange
return upgrades

looking through the offical sheets function page but didn't understand it enough

while isn't a "function"; most programming languages have something equivalent; and nothing about this is a Python question.

It sounds like you'd want to run this through Apps Script.
Menu bar - Extensions -> Apps Script
Copy and paste the script below. Hit save. Hit run and approve the script to run on your account. There's a bit of extra fluff in the code to make it interactable. Go back to the spreadsheet, and access the script from the menu bar Testing -> While. Enter the initial pool in the input box. I had the upgrade count display as an alert.
var upgrade = 0;
var cost = 100;
var costchange = 50;
var going = true;

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Testing');
  menu.addItem('While','whileFunction').addToUi();
}

function whileFunction() {

var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var prompt = ui.prompt('enter value');
var pool = prompt.getResponseText();

while(going === true) {
  if(cost>pool) {
    going = false;
  } else {
    upgrade++;
    pool -= cost;
    cost += costchange;
  }
}

ui.alert('Upgrades: ' + upgrade);

}


The easiest way to do this would be to use a Google Apps Script. It is an easy to use extension accessible from Google Sheets.

Go to Extensions > Apps Script.

Enter the function below into the script editor.

Save the script and give it a name if you'd like.

Return to the document

You should place your input in the A1 cell as specified in the function.

You can call the function in and store the result in any cell by using the formula =upgradeCount()
function upgradeCount() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var originalValue = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
    var checkValue = 100;
    var count = 0;

    while (originalValue > checkValue) {
        originalValue -= checkValue;
        count++;
        checkValue += 50;
    }

    return count;
}



I've tested it and the function works and correctly returns the right value for whatever input you put in A1 which would be the pool variable.
